# How to connect c# with Oracle database specifying the schema name?

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I have a problem trying to connect to oracle database specifying the schema name, when the schema name is different than the user name.

I used to connect using the next String.

But in this case the Schema of the database was the same as the user name.

```
     String con = "data source= (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " + host + ")(PORT = " + port + ")))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = " + servicename + ")));
USER ID=" + user + ";
PASSWORD=" + pass;
```

So the query for login was like

`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='545478';`

Now i have a new user for the conexion, diferent that the Schema, so now i need to change all the sql queries using the Schema name.
For example if the schema name is PRODUCTION_DB the query needs to be change to:

`SELECT * FROM PRODUCTION_DB.usuarios WHERE usuario='545478';`

But I don't want to change all the queries in my code. I prefer to specified the database name in the connection like in MySQL.

How can I change the connection string to add the database name?

For example:

```
String con = "data source= (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " + host + ")(PORT = " + port + ")))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = " + servicename + ")));
USER ID=" + user + ";PASSWORD=" + pass;
 DATABASE = "PRODUCTION_DB";
```

Comment: are you using 32 bit Oracle Client..? if so you do not have to setup the connection string to use `TnsNames` you can still use this style in your app.Config or Web.Config 
I am currently using Oracle and it works this way. 
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConn" connectionString=" Data Source=DataBaseName;User Id=xxx;Password=xxxx;"/>`

Comment: hi, im using the app.config but i dont understand the point.

Comment: what's not to understand.. perhaps you should read up on what the [Configuration Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration(v=vs.110).aspx) is and how it works

Comment: Im already talked to oracle database support. They told me that it is not possible. I need to specified the owner in my queries. So, do you really think you know more than them? Your solution is usuless.

Comment: that's why I currently have it working and with the 32bit Oracle Client on a 64 bit machine you need to set the project from AnyCPU to x86 good luck I have mine working with the simple example I posted in the comments earlier..

Comment: Agree with poster - how does this address changing the default schema? it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in the following way:

```
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString); 
connection.Open();
OracleCommand cm = connection.CreateCommand();
cm.CommandText = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = PRODUCTION_DB";
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: More ways of doing the same thing here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27869/how-to-set-an-oracle-users-default-schema

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string:

```
 string connectionString = "user id=uat;password=*****;data source=localhost:1521/orcl";
 OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
 connection.Open();
```

where:

- orcl - is my database name (SID)
- uat - is a schema name (user name)
- localhost:1521 - are a server name (in my case: localhost) and a port.

Comment: hi @kordirko, thanks for helping me. I need to specified 6 things. **1.-hostname, 2.- password. 3.- host ip 4.- port 5.- SID and 6.- DataBaseName.** In your example you said that SID is the same as the name of the DataBase, but in my case isn't.
Another idea?

Comment: Needs a bit more details, but this definitely helps ! In this weird Oracle world, a schema corresponds to a "user".